# Find the real number $x$ represented by continued fraction $[12;2,2,12,2,2,12,2,2,12\dots]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, continued-fractions

[image]

I need to fins the real vlaue of x for the continued fraction (Image attached)

I have tried partial coefficient method, but didn't get  the exact answer.

I there any way where we can identify the value of x algebrically?

Comment: Hint. Part way down the expression for $x$ you can find another $x$. Put it there. Then expand the fraction and solve.

Comment: @EthanBolker. Bonus: Aint there any other method also?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I don't know another method. A theorem on continued fractions says that one that's eventually periodic is the root of a quadratic equation - but that's essentially what the hint lets you prove.

Comment: I know, but what if it is a ***very*** long sequence? @EthanBolker.

Comment: So how to solve the below expression. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Try to solve $$x=12+\dfrac{1}{2+ \dfrac{1}{2+ \dfrac{1}{x} } }$$

Comment: A simple quadratic, where you want the positive root.

Comment: May you please help solve this as this equation still goes in loop

Comment: As a first step: $$12+\dfrac{1}{2+ \dfrac{1}{2+ \dfrac{1}{x} } } = 12+\dfrac{1}{2+ \dfrac{x}{2x+1 } }= 12+\dfrac{2x+1}{2(2x+1) +x  }.$$   Can you carry on?

Comment: Love you this much! Thanks.. I got 12.4031 as answer

Comment: What is the expression you got?

Comment: @martycohen Presumably $x^2-12 x-5=0$ and so $x= 6 \pm \sqrt{41}$ and you want the positive root